# string cut off after ampersand when using mod rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ampersand

If I have a variable with an ampersand, and try to echo the variable in php, the string is cut off at the ampersand when using mod rewrite URL's.

The variable is `search & search`

When using:

```
page.php?s=search+%26+search
```

I can echo the complete variable. `search & search`

When using rewritten URL's:

```
page/search+%26+search/
```

I echo the variable and it prints  `search`

What needs to be added to htaccess to fix this?

current htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\s=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1? [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The char **&** is a query key value seperater, it can not be used in uri , that is the main reason why you are getting an unexpected output a

Comment: Yep, `page.php?s=search+%26+search` is correct usage and `page/search+%26+search/` is incorrect usage. `/page/?search+%26+search` would be correct usage.

Comment: ^^ misleading. To use ampersand in rewrite url, just double encode them. e.g. `/page/search+%2526+search`. To use plus symbol in rewrite urls, encode them three times. For instance `/page/search + search` would be `page/search+%25252B+search`